Download Instagram reel audio only with Instaloader/Python or any way
I am trying to download the audio in the following format
https://www.instagram.com/reels/audio/1997779980583970/. Below code is returning "Fetching metadata failed".
I am able to download the reels but not separate audio files.
What shall I do?
def get_reel_audio_data(audio_id):
    loader = instaloader.Instaloader()
    try:
        # Fetch the audio post using the audio ID
        audio_post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(loader.context, audio_id)
        audio_url = audio_post.video_url if audio_post.is_video else audio_post.url
        return audio_url, True
    except Exception as e:
        if settings.DEBUG:
            import traceback
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        capture_exception(e)
        return None, False


You could use something like selenium to press the 'download' button with a proper browser

Read the service's robots.txt at https://www.theirdomain.example/robots.txt to make sure you comply with their policy on automatic data retrieval,
and look into their privacy policy for the same purpose also.
And at your own responsibility,
You need to discover the URL to the audio file itself. The URL to the reel won't do. While it has a link to the sound with a button, you can't download directly based on the reel URL or the button, as they're not audio files and your download method probably needs it.
Use your browser's inspect mode or similarly named function to view the source code.
Open up the browser's tool for inspecting elements, follow the path of what the button to play the sound does, and see if you can find the raw file it points to. My simple example will only work if it does - but I found it.
Once you find the audio file pointed to, such as
<audio src="https://exampleserver.net/v/examplepath/examplefilename.m4a?exampleslugs"></audio>
or similar, you can test that the file is downloadable, and proceed writing python code logic for handling it:

extract from this HTML tag the URL pointed to
use the URL in the code you already tried to verify downloading works

To build a reusable tool for applying an automated method to any reel, we could assume the service you're scraping from would keep their HTML structure the same between different reels. Then find the audio files by similar "path" under the reel page each time.
Your browser's inspect tool gives the full XPath to the raw file you find manually:
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/audio
You can then use that XPath in your Python code to find the audio tag I used as an example.
If you find the assumption of same XPath for all reels doesn't hold, you could try other strategies such as finding all .m4a URLs from the webpage.
Note that if you don't comply with the service's usage policies, your code will likely not run for long after testing.

You cannot use instaloader directly to download audio since it designed to get images/videos and metadata only. If you want an audio without using python and coding there are no of browser extensions available. (MediaSave, Audio Downloader Prime)
If you want to use python, I tried to scrape the data from beautiful soup but instagram didn't allow me to do that and it failed to retrieve audio.
So there is 2 option,

Instagram API may provide a way to access media related metadata.

Use Selenium to automate browser, load the data and extract the
audio.


For the Second Option, the following code might be work for some audio.
def get_reel_audio_data(audio_url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')  #to fast the process we can run the browser without displaying GUI
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    driver.get(audio_url) # get audio URL
    audio_tag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@property='og:audio']")  # Search og:audio meta tag
    audio_url = audio_tag.get_attribute('content')

    driver.quit()
    return audio_url


audio_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/reels/audio/1997779980583970/'
audio_link = get_reel_audio_data(audio_url)
print(f"Audio URL: {audio_link}")

This might be work some audio but you should handle the error depend on the situation.
